# Does SessionAuthenticationModule set IClaimsPrincipal on Thread.Principal or HttpContext.Current.User

Tags: wif

Wouldn't it be a mistake to set it on the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ***HttpContext.Current.User*** and ***Thread.CurrentPrincipal*** are set with an IClaimsPrincipal (the same instance in fact)